# Boolean equation from circuit

Tags: boolean-logic, boolean-expression, circuit

Could someone please help me understand what the boolean equation performed by this circuit would be?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Label the output of the first mux X.

Then, create a truth table for X, then Y:

```
C D X A Y
---------
0 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 0 0
1 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 1
0 0 1 1 1
0 1 0 1 1
1 0 0 1 1
1 1 1 1 1
```

From inspection of the truth table:

```
Y = A + CD + C'D'
```

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to write A + (C XOR D)' ?

Comment: Yes, `A + (C XOR D)'` would be equivalent.  Whether it's easier/better depends upon the primitives allowed or prefered.